# How do I setup SSL for Jruby Oracle connection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle, ssl

In Rails, Jruby etc. I've created a functioning call that queries an Oracle database in a webpage. I need to secure that functioning call in SSL.

```
<%
require 'jdbc_connection'

# Database settings
user   = "***REMOVED***"
passwd = "***REMOVED***"
url    = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@***REMOVED***:1521/test"
output = ""
error = ""

select_stmt, rest, select_sql = nil
error = "No Errors."
begin
  conn = OracleConnection.create(user, passwd, url)
  select_sql = "select columnA from test.tableA WHERE name='"+@subject["name"].first+"'"
  select_stmt = conn.create_statement
  rset = select_stmt.execute_query select_sql
  while (rset.next)
    output = output + rset.getString(1)
  end

rescue
  error = "Failed executing Oracle demo from JRuby ", $!, "\n"

  ensure
   # We have to ensure everything is closed here.
   if (!select_stmt.nil?)
    select_stmt.close
   end
   if (!rset.nil?)
    rset.close
   end
   conn.close_connection
end
%>
```

I think I need a reference to the keystore, username, password, and connection string.

I found an example connection String on this site:https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/ssl-connection-to-oracle-db-using-jdbc,-tlsv12,-jks-or-oracle-wallets

```
DB_USER = "hr", DB_PASSWORD ="hr", and 
DB_URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION= (ADDRESS=
                   (PROTOCOL=TCPS)(PORT=1522)(HOST=myhost))
                   (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=myorcldbservicename))
                   (SECURITY=(ssl_server_cert_dn="CN=testcert.oracle.com, O=Oracle Corporation,L=Redwood City,ST=California,C=US")))"
```

Where do I reference the keystore? I feel like the class OracleConnection should probably be something like OracleConnectionSSL?

Comment: Did you create `jdbc_connection.rb` yourself? What's in it? You normally set Oracle SSL settings in Java as JSSE properties on the JDBC connection object (e.g. `javax.net.ssl.keyStore`).

Comment: It's basically an interface to the driver. It's provided by Oracle here:https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/jruby-oracle11g-330825.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, this is only half an answer - I don't know much about JRuby, but from the Oracle side - [this Oracle PDF describes how to set up SSL with the Oracle JDBC Thin driver](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/wp-oracle-jdbc-thin-ssl-130128.pdf). You'll probably want to read the whole thing, but here's their Java example for using JKS keystores (slightly different for Oracle Wallets):

```
String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps(HOST=servername)(PORT=2484))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=servicename))))";
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("user", "scott");
props.setProperty("password", "tiger"); 
props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore",
 "D:\\client_jks\\keystore.jks");
props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType","JKS");
props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","welcome123"); 
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
```

You see how it's setting up the Java properties before it calls DriverManager.getConnection? I think that'll need to go in your `jdbc_connection` interface before the same getConnection call there. But I'm not familiar enough with Ruby to know how to do that.

Comment: This put me on the right path to create a solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to set the JKS connection properties. 
(a) Programmatically using the connection properties. See the sample [DataSourceForJKS.java](https://github.com/oracle/oracle-db-examples/blob/master/java/jdbc/ConnectionSamples/DataSourceForJKS.java)

(b) You can set these properties as system properties.

```
-Doracle.net.ssl_server_dn_match=true  
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=${TNS_ADMIN}/truststore.jks  
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=welcome1  
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=${TNS_ADMIN}/keystore.jks  
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=welcome1
```

(c) If you are using 18.3 then, you can leverage ojdbc.properties to add these connection properties. Check out the [blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/whats-new-in-183-jdbc-and-ucp)